# Why are mounted iso's not browseable via an NFS share/mount?

Tags: mount, iso, nfs

Try it out please:
download an iso and place it in /data/iso
eg:

```
[root@geppetto ~]# ls -al /data/iso
total 708620
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root      4096 Oct 17 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root      4096 Oct 17 14:36 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 725614592 Jul  7 19:26 CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso
```

Then mount it

```
 [root@geppetto ~]# mkdir -p /media/centos6.3-64-live
 [root@geppetto ~]# 
 [root@geppetto ~]# mount -t iso9660 /data/iso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso /media/centos6.3-64-live
```

then export it's parentdir via nfs,

```
[root@geppetto ~]# cat /etc/exports 
/export/iso cal-26.oma.be(ro)
[root@geppetto ~]# 
[root@geppetto ~]# service nfs reload
[root@geppetto ~]# showmount -e 
Export list for geppetto.oma.be:
/export/iso cal-26.oma.be
[root@geppetto ~]#
```

Then mount it on the client

```
[root@cal-26 ~]# mount -v -t nfs puppet-me.oma.be:/export/iso /geppettoiso
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Oct 25 13:39:16 2012
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.16.49,clientaddr=192.168.15.194'
[root@cal-26 ~]#
```

On the NFS server it is browsable:

```
[root@geppetto media]# ls -al
total 10
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Oct 17 15:23 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 26 root root 4096 Oct 25 11:28 ..
dr-xr-xr-x.  5 root root 2048 Jul  7 19:23 centos6.3-64-live
[root@geppetto media]# 
[root@geppetto media]# ls -al /media/centos6.3-64-live/
total 30
dr-xr-xr-x. 5 root root  2048 Jul  7 19:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Oct 17 15:23 ..
dr-xr-xr-x. 3 root root  2048 Jul  7 19:22 EFI
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 18416 Jul  7 19:23 GPL
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root  2048 Jul  7 19:23 isolinux
dr-xr-xr-x. 2 root root  2048 Jul  7 19:24 LiveOS
[root@geppetto media]#
```

but on the nfs client it looks just like if it is the original iso  file:

```
[root@cal-26 geppettoiso]# ls -al /geppettoiso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 725614592 Jul  7 19:26 /geppettoiso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso
[root@cal-26 geppettoiso]#
```

original file:

```
[root@geppetto media]# ls -al /data/iso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 725614592 Jul  7 19:26 /data/iso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso
[root@geppetto media]#
```

just for completeness:

```
[root@cal-26 geppettoiso]# mount | grep -i iso
puppet-me.oma.be:/export/iso on /geppettoiso type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.15.194,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.16.49)
[root@cal-26 geppettoiso]# 


[root@geppetto media]#  mount | grep -i iso
/data/iso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso on /media/centos6.3-64-live type iso9660 (ro,loop=/dev/loop0)
/data/iso on /export/iso type none (rw,bind)
[root@geppetto media]#
```

Comment: FYI: if you try to export the mounted iso, it gives no error, but if you try to mount that on an nfs client, you get on the client, that the clientdir is not a directory:

eg:
root@cal-00:~# mount -v -t nfs puppet-me.oma.be:/data/iso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso /mnt/geppettoiso
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Oct 25 10:31:25 2012
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.16.49,clientaddr=192.168.15.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Not a directory
mount.nfs: mount point /mnt/geppettoiso is not a directory
root@cal-00:~#

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, once your NFS share is mounted, simply mount the ISO on the *client* machine. The NFS share is treated as part of the local filesystem.

---

Source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/browsing-an-iso-file-in-a-nfs-share-547209/

Comment: Sorry for being a pain Kyle, what you say works indeed : "mount -t iso9660 /geppettoiso/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-LiveCD.iso /media/centos-iso" But the reference you give is not explaining my question. The NFS share is treated as part of the filesystem, but not the isomount. Why is the iso-mount lost through the nfs-mount? BTW: I am trying to make the clientside as light as possible, since it is intended to be a pxe-install.